# Extracting 25 words to both sides of a word from a text

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds

I have the following text and I am trying to use this pattern to extract 25 words to each side of the matches. The challenge is that the matches overlap, thus python regex engine takes only one match. I would appreciate if anyone can help fix this

Text

2015 Outlook  The Company is providing the following outlook for 2015 in lieu of formal financial guidance at this time. This outlook does not include the impact of any future acquisitions and transaction-related costs.  Revenues - Based on the revenues from the fourth quarter of 2014, the addition of new items at our some facility and the previously opened acquisition of Important Place, the Company expects utilization of the current 100 items to remain in some average

I tried the following pattern

```
pattern = r'(?<=outlook\s)((\w+.*?){25})'
```

This creates one match whereas i need two matches and it should not matter whether one overlaps the other

I need basically two matches

Comment: have you tried re.findall?

Comment: What are expected matches here?

Comment: Do you have to use regex for this?

Comment: I don't have to use regex, but I would like to. Expected matches are two strings containing 25 words after 'outlook', since there are 2 outlooks.

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'(?=outlook\s+(\w+(?:\W+\w+){25}))', s)`. If there can be less than 25 words, replace `{25}` with `{1,25}` or even `{0,25}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use regex at all -the python `module re` does not handle overlapping ranges...

```
text = """2015 Outlook The Company is providing the following outlook for 2015 in lieu of formal financial guidance at this time. This outlook does not include the impact of any future acquisitions and transaction-related costs. Revenues - Based on the revenues from the fourth quarter of 2014, the addition of new items at our some facility and the previously opened acquisition of Important Place, the Company expects utilization of the current 100 items to remain in some average"""

lookfor = "outlook"

# split text at spaces
splitted = text.lower().split()

# get the position in splitted where the words match (remove .,-?! for comparison) 
positions = [i for i,w in enumerate(splitted) if lookfor == w.strip(".,-?!")]


# printing here, you can put those slices in a list for later usage
for p in positions:    # positions is: [1, 8, 21]
    print( ' '.join(splitted[max(0,p-26):p+26]) )
    print()
```

Output:

```
2015 outlook the company is providing the following outlook for 2015 in lieu of formal financial guidance at this time. this outlook does not include the impact

2015 outlook the company is providing the following outlook for 2015 in lieu of formal financial guidance at this time. this outlook does not include the impact of any future acquisitions and transaction-related costs.

2015 outlook the company is providing the following outlook for 2015 in lieu of formal financial guidance at this time. this outlook does not include the impact of any future acquisitions and transaction-related costs. revenues - based on the revenues from the fourth quarter of 2014, the
```

By iterating the splitted words you get the positions and slice the splitted list. Make sure to start at `0` for the slice even if `p-26` is lower then `0`, else you wont get any output. (Start of -4 means from the end of string)

Comment: Thank you Patrick, that's what I wanted to know since I could not find whether it can handle overlapping or not.

Answer (score 0):

A **non-regex** way:

```
string = "2015 Outlook The Company is providing the following outlook for 2015 in lieu of formal financial guidance at this time. This outlook does not include the impact of any future acquisitions and transaction-related costs. Revenues - Based on the revenues from the fourth quarter of 2014, the addition of new items at our some facility and the previously opened acquisition of Important Place, the Company expects utilization of the current 100 items to remain in some average"
words = string.split()
starting25 = " ".join(words[:25])
ending25 = " ".join(words[-25:])
print(starting25)
print("\n")
print(ending25)
```

Comment: Thanks @user2229219. I thought about it as well, but that would be longer and if there are multiple matches I would have to generate those texts for each. I would like to use regex for this but if there's no other way then I plan to use splitting.